# Issue returning type from Solidity to Javascript

Tags: javascript, solidity

First of all, to facilitate the understanding of the problem, I will keep only the functions that could be more useful to grasp the issue. The code allows for the creation of an NFT within an array, where the first NFT has an idToken of 0.
I'd like to pass the argument 0 to the readContract(tokenid) JavaScript function to display the Power value, a uint8 (randomly generated with a value from 0 to 100), when I click the "Get data from contract" button in the HTML file. Unfortunately, I'm getting an error and I've tried various ways to resolve it without success. The contract and JavaScript are properly connected (as evidenced by the connectContract() function, which is a verification of this) and so ABI and Address aren't part of the issue.
The readContract() function should use the getNFTPower method written in the Solidity contract, but something seems to be going wrong: returned values aren't valid. But to me they are LOL...
I had also tried inserting some console.log statements in the readContract() function before and after the first line of code:
`const power = await window.contract.methods.getNFTPower(tokenId).call();` 
I don't see any console.log output after this statement, so the problem seems to be occurring there.

Hope someone could give me a hint.. Thanks.

Following the error screenshots
[image]
[image]

Following part of the code.

**SOLIDITY code**

```
contract NFTGame is ERC721, Ownable {
    using SafeMath for uint256;

    address public erc20TokenAddress;

    struct NFTAttributes {
        uint8 power;
        bool inArena;
    }

    NFTAttributes[] public nfts;

    constructor(address _erc20TokenAddress) ERC721(FightArena, FIGA) payable {
        erc20TokenAddress = _erc20TokenAddress;
    }

    function createNFT() external {
        uint8 power = uint8(uint256(keccak256(abi.encodePacked(block.timestamp, msg.sender))) % 101);  Random number da 0 a 100
        nfts.push(NFTAttributes(power, false));
        uint256 tokenId = nfts.length - 1;
        _mint(msg.sender, tokenId);
    }

    function getNFTPower(uint256 tokenId) public view returns (uint8) {
    require(_exists(tokenId), ID del token non valido);
    return uint8(nfts[tokenId].power);
}
 
}
```

**HTML/JS**

```
...
<head>
...
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/web3/1.2.7-rc.0/web3.min.js"></script>
...
</head>
...
<body>
    <button onclick="connectMetamask()">CONNECT METAMASK</button> <br>
    <p id="accountArea"></p>
    <button onclick="connectContract()">CONNECT TO CONTRACT</button> <br>
    <p id="contractArea"></p>
    <button onclick="readContract(0)">GET DATA FROM CONTRACT</button> <br>
    <p id="dataArea"></p> // 0 is the first NFT minted by the function createNFT()
...
</body>
...
<script>
...
const readContract = async (tokenId) => {
    const power = await window.contract.methods.getNFTPower(tokenId).call();
    const powerString = power.toString(); 
    document.getElementById("dataArea").innerHTML = "Power of NFT " + tokenId + ": " + powerString;
}
...
</script>
...
```

I tried rewriting the function readContract() in various ways, but it wasn't helpful. My goal is to click the "GET DATA FROM CONTRACT" button and display the POWER value of the NFT's tokenId that I will pass as an argument (in the case of the code above, the first NFT, tokenId = 0).

Answer (score 1):

There are two most common causes :

1. If you are using abi and a contract address correct.
2. If you selected the correct network, for example, if your contract is on testnet you can select testnet or if your contract is on Mainnet select the Mainnet.

Comment: ABI and Contract are obtained from REMIX once the deployment is done, so they are correct. In fact, the function connectContract() works, whereas if I enter (for example) a wrong ABI, it doesn't connect me to the contract. 
The contract uses the Ethereum ERC20 token address (0xae7ab96520DE3A18E5e111B5EaAb095312D7fE84). Everything works correctly within the contract; clicking on the getNFTPower function returns the correct value. The contract is more complex, and I've provided a truncated version here, but it enables NFTs to battle each other. All these functions work on the SEPOLIA testnet.

Comment: Maybe I'm not using Sepolia on Ganache, but simply the Ethereum network... perhaps that's why. However, all transactions on the contract still work the same way...

Comment: Thank you Deepanshu, it was an address error... LOL. Thanks. Not it works.